# How to write all build details in a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want all build details to be saved in a text file.How to get the details is it by using the post build event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a batch file and just pipe the output to a file

For example, create a build.bat file and add the following:

```
:: Test build script
:: Setup command line for build
if "%DevEnvDir%=="" (
   echo "Setting up PATH"
   :: use VS80 for VS2005 solution, VS90 for VS2008 solution,
   :: or VS100 for VS2010 solution
   call %VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" x86
)
msbuild YourProject.sln /t:Rebuild /propertyConfiguration=release > Log.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo "Build Succeeded"
if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo "Build Failed, See Log.txt"
```

This is just an example, but this would log the output to Log.txt file.

Comment: This would require runnign a build froma command line rather than Visual Studio, some more work required in order to be able running such msbuild script whilst Visual Studio Build action, for instance this could be added as `AfterBuild` targets but of the specific project